# Appropriate approach for developing dynamically update-able Flutter app on Linux

Tags: flutter, dynamic-loading, flutter-linux

What I want to implement ( linux platform )

- My app could load and unload particular widget from different packages which is built separately.
- The new widget could be replaced on run-time.
- My app could change particular widget without re-build ideally (optional).

I found some available features on Flutter for my app.

- Deferred Components : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Deferred-Components
- flutter_eval package : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_eval

Question

- it looks 'deferred components' is not supported on linux desktop. Anyone knows the plan supporting it on linux platform ?
- I'm checking 'flutter_eval' package for my app. But, I'm not sure it is correct. Anyone knows alternative approach for mine ?